# Something wrong with RegExp or the loop

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to count how many times a letter has been pressed. I wrote the program (I have to use only JS), most of it, but I seem to have encountered a problem.

If the input from the keyboard is "w s s d", it will say that "letter w was pressed once" and "letter s was pressed 2 times". Letter D is not displayed at all. And, to be honest, I can't see what could be the problem.

```
for(index = 0; index< inputList.length; index++) {        
    if(str != null && patt.test(str) && inputList[index].trim().length > 0) {
        var match1 = str.match(new RegExp(inputList[index], "g"));                        
        if(match1 != null){

        output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + ('<span>Letter ' + inputList[index] + " was pressed " + match1.length + " times</span><br/>");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp(inputList[index], "g"), '');
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the fiddle: [code](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dQR6j/14/)

Comment: You should include the relevant code here, as well as linking to a fiddle.

Comment: What is inputList? You say you think your regular expression is wrong but the don't show us the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After printing the number of times, put this:

```
index = index + match1.length - 1;
```

This is because you are always increasing `index` by 1 even when keys are pressed more times, which means when you have `w s s d`, you're looping through indexes `0 1 2` instead of `0 1 3` (2 is skipped because `s` occurs twice).

[fiddle edited](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dQR6j/16/)

Comment: it actually makes sense. True that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an answer. More of a question. All I did was add this while debugging, which should have no effect whatsoever. But it does, and tada, everything works.

```
patt.test(str);
```

[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sabof/L63fM/)

Comment: it works just fine in fiddle, but it doesn't do anything in the actual code :/  a string like "a a s a d" displays only the 3 a's and 1 d. No s.. but the fiddle is ok, though..